# How to make a sticky menubar in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a sticky menubar in my html website.

But can't make it sticky.

**html markup**

```
<header class="header__container" id="myHeader">
     /*navbar html part is here*/
</header>
```

**css part**

```
.sticky 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content 
{
    padding-top: 102px;
}
```

**js code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky)
  {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  }
  else 
  {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Where is the problem can't find it

Comment: please provide working fiddle or snippet code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky)
  {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  }
  else 
  {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 9000px;
}

.sticky 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.sticky + .content 
{
    padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header__container" id="myHeader">
     <nav class="content">
       <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
</header>
```

Explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: While I scrolling down, I want my navbar is fixed on the top of the page... That's I want

Comment: So where is the problem? In example everything is working

Comment: Ya...working..but in my code it doesn't. My html part is huge part. That's why I can't share those code

Comment: If it is doesn't work, I think your code may have Javascript conflict issue, you need to check the order priority of your external JS files.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are giving `w3schools` code....I also applied this...but in my code it doesn't work brother

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, Your `header` will get `fixed` after scrolling `100px` as per my script. It will add class `scrolled` to make the `header` `fixed`

```js
let $window = $(window),
        $document = $("document"),
        $body = $("body");
        
/*
     * Header Fix on Scroll
     */

    let fixHeader = ($stickyEl, $scrollToPosition) => {

        if ($stickyEl.length > 0) {

            let scrollPostion = "";

            $window.scroll(() => {

                scrollPostion = $window.scrollTop();

                scrollPostion > $scrollToPosition ? $stickyEl.addClass("scrolled") : $stickyEl.removeClass("scrolled");
            });
        }
    };

    // Call fixed header function
    fixHeader($(".header__container"), 100);
```

```css
.scrolled 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 600px; /* Just to check sticky header */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header__container" id="myHeader">
     /*navbar html part is here*/
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing window offset to a value should set page scrolling position. 
I have only changed `window.pageYOffset >= 100` from your JS.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<header class="container" id="myHeader">
  /*navbar html part is here*/
</header>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error
  sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
  consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
  voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel
  illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur
</div>
```